# Empty file when saving signed PDFs from DocuSign Connect

Tags: docusignapi

I'm getting blank PDFs when saving signed PDF documents from DocuSign from Connect event notification. 
As I understand it the PDFBytes value is Base64 encoded, so this is my code to convert that into a string:

```
XmlNode docs = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//a:DocumentPDFs", mgr);
                foreach (XmlNode doc in docs.ChildNodes)
                {
                    string documentName = doc.ChildNodes[0].InnerText; 
                    string documentId = doc.ChildNodes[2].InnerText;      
                    string byteStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(doc.ChildNodes[1].InnerText));                    
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(LOGPATH + envelopeId.InnerText + "_" + documentId + "_" + documentName, byteStr);
                }
```

However, this produces empty PDFs. Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: Can you please post the value of `doc.ChildNodes[1].InnerText`

Comment: You can view the notification xml at http://documentsigningdemo.networxsolutions.co.uk/documents/ffb3019a-c529-4f48-8085-64238d9a1c52_Completed_55e20fde-d56e-44b4-be3d-4f778c896b0e.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to encode the bytes after converting the Base64 string. Try this

```c#
byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(doc.ChildNodes[1].InnerText);
string filePath = LOGPATH + envelopeId.InnerText + "_" + documentId + "_" + documentName + ".pdf";
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath , fileBytes);
```

Comment: I've tried this and am now getting PDFs which fail to load.

Comment: I've now given up on extracting the file from the xml and am now using a call to the GetDocument Api method, which is working for me.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try again. You are not required to make the additional GetDocument call.